# React for web, react native for mobile app development

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking into hybrid development. After some googling, it points to me that there are some potential in investing some time learning React and React native. Dont ask me about Angular, hated Angular due to its complexity. My question is does learning React helps in developing mobile apps with React native?

Regards,
Xing

Comment: Don't really understand your question. Yes learning React helps you develop React Native. There are only little different between them. For example you want to put text, in React you use basic html tag like <p>. In React Native you use component <Text>.

Answer (score 0):

```
React-native : This is Mobile Application Development(Hybrid mobile Apps)
React: This is Web Application  Development.
```

Now in this Case those React and React-native Component life cycle Same.
but your using Some methods and components are Different then react to react-native. But mostly both are same. Except Components.

So , Finally  if you are learned react and react native Definitely you will develop in this both. 
**`But If you learned React you will Develop Only WebApps`**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when I started learning React Native, I had to get the concepts used in React. Basically you will take on React first, before proceeding into any offshoots. A solid foundation in the React style of programming will help a lot in React Native.

The following link is a good guideline. Read this for a start. And also the Facebook documentation for React. This may take some time, so if you have the time, you can proceed. Else try to cut it short when it comes to maybe webpack and stuff like that.

https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto

And then there are many tutorials in React Native. You can again start with the Facebook documentation for that.

Comment: any other alternative(websites) for learning react-native from  Facebook documentation because we have proxy #forbeginner .